# What algorithm is used in response file for silent install of worklight 6

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

the documentation http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_silent_installation.html
show an example of response file where the password is encryted like that :

```
<data key='user.database.mysql.password2' value='{xyzzy}XBT17OD3N32AW5NLAE'/>
```

How can i generate the password ? Does {xyzzy} stand for the algorithm used to encrypt the password ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can stick in the plain-text password, like this:

`<data key='user.database.mysql.password2' value='unGuessable'/>`

Or, if you want to avoid having plain-text passwords in text files, you can run Installation Manager in wizard mode with the option to record a response file (even on a different platform or with a different database type) and then extract the obfuscated password from the generated response file.